# Separating Error Checking from a method - SOLID Principles

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have the following method that I believes violates the single responsibility principle as I'm doing a query, checking for input errors, and controlling the re-propmt of the username.

Issue is I'm not sure how I would design this in a way to "not" be intertwined.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

```
public List<UserModel> UserNameCheck(IDataAccess _data, string connection, ref List<UserModel> userQuery, ref string userName)
        {
            bool valid;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                string checkUser = _queryString.CheckUser($"{ userName }");
                userQuery = _data.LoadData<UserModel, dynamic>(checkUser, new { }, connection);
                valid = QueryIsNullOrNot("Invalid username, please try again", userQuery);
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    _systemMessaging.ExceededLoginAttempts();
                    _systemMessaging.SystemExitMessage();
                    System.Environment.Exit(1);
                }
                else if (valid == false)
                {
                    _systemMessaging.InvalidUser(userName);
                    _systemMessaging.UserNamePrompt();
                    userName = _retrieveUserInput.Input();
                }
                else
                {
                    return userQuery;
                }
            }
            return userQuery = null;
   }
```

Comment: If the situation is that you're learning C#, and you're bothering with SOLID right from the start, I'd say it's too soon. Also, I suspect this question isn't suitable here on SO.

Comment: Assuming the code works as intended, I would suggest to re-ask your question on [CodeReview.se], by perhaps including the whole class (CR posts can be as long as they need to be) so readers/reviewers have as much context as possible; describe what the code does / what problem it's solving, and you'll get feedback on every aspect of it, from naming conventions to unsuspected edge cases and adherence to standards including SOLID. Good luck!

Comment: Ahhh I wasn't aware of that site. I will take my question there. Thanks!